# What is the importance of clock in flipflops

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I understand that the difference between latches and flipflops that the value stored in flipflops can be changed on pulse only in clock intervals.
But what is the real need to do it?
I mean if value can be changed by inputs why it should be also controlled by the system clock?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid errors during transitions. 
(google "Electronics glitch")

If you have for example 2 inputs they may change at the same time producing unexpected result during this transition.

For example:
A=1, B=0, A+B=1 (+ = OR)
if they change at same time:
A=0, B=1, A+B=1
but during this transition when A=0, B may be rising but still represents B=0 and you will get A+B=0 for short interval.

By changing all flipflops states only on CLK edge then till next edge all signals should became stable and logic will perform on desired values.